# How to reset a preference to its previous value in Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have an extension that allows users to change the home page and new tab page. I do so by changing the values of some preferences (e.g. browser.startup.homepage, browser.newtab.url).

I want to reset the values of these preferences to previous values(not default) when the user uninstalls the extension.

How to reset the preference to its previous value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
const ps = Cc['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
ps.clearUserPref('full.path.to.pref.here');
```

Note: This reset pref to default value, if no default value is set the pref is deleted.

Comment: I want to save the users preferences before changing them and reset them to saved(not browser defaults) values when uninstalling the extension.How to do that?

Comment: On uninstalling you want to delete the prefs? This is good practice, I would think you would reset the on the default branch and then reset your branch, that should delete the prefs

Comment: thanks it works for resetting the pref to default value. But i stored the pref value and then using event listeners set the pref to the saved value on uninstallation..